# SSRS "The requested functionality is not currently enabled"

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

What does this log error mean? "The requested functionality is not currently enabled"

library!ReportServer_0-193!46ac!08/14/2018-13:04:15:: i INFO: Call to GetReportParametersAction(/XYZ/ABC/MyReport).
library!ReportServer_0-193!46ac!08/14/2018-13:04:15:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.NotEnabledException: , Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.NotEnabledException: The requested functionality is not currently enabled.;

My report runs find in VS and in SSRS intranet server!
So what is the issue?
Result from the server says: "Processing: 0 processed of 52 total; 0 errors."
So if there is no error here what does the log error mean and why is not the front-end in sync with the back-end.

My report has three parameters CustomerNo and a date range Start and End dates.
All of which I set in the Data Driven Subscription. There is nothing wrong with the inputs as I have checked all of these.

The path and filename are all correct, no nulls.

I created the destination sub folder so I assume it inherits the security of the parent so I don't believe it is permission issue, if it is surely the log would tell me!?

I have also deleted my subscription and started again to no avail.

I am lost to even no where to start looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a work around perhaps somebody else could share there experience! To let me know if you had a similar issue and how you resolved it if you did that was different to what I am about to describe that is move away from dataset to use defaults.

Might I add the log didn't update until would you believe an hour later to show the actual error as I checked the timestamp and the error mentioned was "... Default value or value provided for the report parameter 'FromDate' is not valid." So Got nothing to say other than @#$%^&.

It seems the problem was one or perhaps both of my date parameters as set in the data driven query were not compatible. So I ended up changing from using the option from "Get value from dataset" to "Use default value", then in my proc called by the report I set the default to NULL, then wrote script code that checked if the value of the date parameter was NULL then change to the desired default value, which is fine for what I needed that is to base it on first day of the month using GETDATE().

I didn't bother investigating further so I am not sure if it is locale issue since I am running on a Australian DMY server and perhaps input gets sent in MDY order or this is a SSRS bug! Who knows that was a few hours of time I will never get back over something that should have just worked.